# Facebook iOS SDK v3.1: How can I logout the previous user in my app when a different user logs in at Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

If the user logs out from the Facebook app, my app won't be affected. Then if he logs in with a different account through Facebook app, my app can't detect it.

How can I detect if a different user/account is using my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the facebook user's id (and more) using the graph api:

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",user.id);
    }
}];
```

You can use that to detect which user is using your app.

Comment: `[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"%@", user.id)}]`

the logged user.id is still the id of the previous user, not the current user on Facebook App / Safari

Comment: I dont think you can find what a user is doing outside of your app unless you reauthorize each time you come back to your app.